# jQuery queue, how does it work EXACTLY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue, jquery-animate

I'm having a hard time figuring out how queue's work in jQuery, especially the `fx` queue.  What I want to do is:

**Animate multiple different elements one after another**

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zusr/2/) first.  When you click on the button, both of the elements are being animated.  Now I know I can do something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8JU7/), where I put the animation in the callback of the first animation, but this isn't an option because I have a situation where I have a pool of animations, and I want to arbitrarily run any of them in a particular sequence.  For example, I might have animations A, B, C, D, and E which all animate different elements.  Sometimes I will want to execute in the order B->A->C, another time I might want A->B->C.

How can I use queues to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your animations are moving different elements, you might be better off managing your own queue than doing it with jquery's.  You could store the animations you want to run in an array.

```
animations = [animation_a, animation_b, animation_c];
```

and then at the end of each animation call the function which runs the next one.  Like:

```
function run_next() {
    if ( animations.length > 0 ) {
        next_animation = animations.shift();
        next_animation();
    }
}

function animation_a() {
    $("#element1").slideDown(500, run_next);
} 

function animation_b() {
    $("#element2").animate({left:'-=200'},1500, run_next);
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGsrA/7/).

Comment: This is decent, and what I imagined a solution would look like, basically chaining animations in the callbacks of each other.  The beef I have with this method is the `run_next` in the call back of the animation.  Seems a little intrusive and creating a strong coupling between the actual animation vs the queue.  In my perfect world, I just have animations, A, B, C that are not coupled with any other object, and I can just throw them into a queue, and the queue will handle them appropriately.

Comment: It's certainly possible to decouple the animations from the queue.  You could create a queue object and each animation could be a closure which knows which queue it's attached to.  But that would require a lot more code and complexity.  Do you really need that?

Comment: @Leopd: This method still doesn't work, both animations are called at the same time; the only reason it looks queued is because the you set the first animation to be faster than the second. I put in logging so you can see all that the functions triggered at the same time.  To have it queued, you need to a waiting algorithm, something similar to the one in my post

Comment: It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/UGsrA/8/ .  Vinceh changed the "if" from my original post to a "while" when he tried to implement my suggestion in a fiddle and I didn't fix it back until now.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you have all the A,B,C...N have the same class just to select them in an array.

And each element has its animation property that you want to do with that.

Like we have a `DIV`s :

```
<div class="animateMe" properties="{Left: +=50}" duration="2000", easing="linear"></div>
<div class="animateMe" properties="{Top: +=50}" duration="1000", easing="linear"></div>
```

Then selecting all the DIVs will be like.

```
var elements = $('div.animateMe') // Get all the objects in an array
```

Now there is a jQuery [shuffle](http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-shuffle-plugin/) plugin that will help you in shuffling the array you have selected.

```
elements = $.shuffle( elements );
```

Now You can use `.each()` function to animate individually.

```
$.each( elements, function(){
    var properties = this.attr('properties');
    var duration= this.attr('duration');
    var easing= this.attr('easing');
    this.animate( properties, duration, easing );
});
```

Comment: Seems a bit odd to have to add a specific class to every element in which I want to animate.

Comment: Its just a general idea. The common class was only used to select the elements A,B....N. Nothing more. It can be achieved by so many other ways.

Answer (score 0):

**Update (working)**

The code below does what you want; it is based off of the custom queue from Leopd.  It does not use jQuery's queues or deferred objects though: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/FPGrj/

```
var q = ['div1', 'div2', 'div3', 'div4'];
var next_div = q.shift();

$("button").click( function() {
    animate_div();
});

function animate_div() {
    if ( q.length > 0 ) {
        curr_div = next_div;
        next_div = q.shift();
        $('#' + curr_div).hide(2000,animate_div);
    }
    else {
        $('#' + next_div).hide(2000);
    }
}
```

The crossed out code was the original solution using deferred objects.   It does not produce the functionality desired by the OP.  It just serves to shorten the amount of code needed to chain **multiple animations** to a single object; it does **not** serve to chain animations across **multiple objects**

<strike>You want to make use of [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).  For your case, it is especially easy since animations are already creating [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) objects: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/fpseA/</strike>

```
$("button").click( function() {
    $('#div1').growWidth().growHeight();
});

$.fn.growWidth = function () {
    return this.animate({width: 200});
}

$.fn.growHeight = function () {
   return this.animate({height: 200});
}
```

Comment: You are right, it doesn't help with the problem you have.  The queue object seems to be encapsulated within the object being animated.  If you can find a way to attach that queue to another object, say a parent div, it would solve the issue.  I'll update if I discover a method to do that.

Comment: @vinceh: check the update.  it has a working queue.  If I have time, I'll see if I can implement this into an extension